# Rails efficient way to query data between associate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assume the following rule

```
manager has_many serial_tasks
serial_task has_many tasks
task belongs_to project
```

Now I have a manager, how do I efficiently query all projects'id?

Here is what I wrote, but I thought it's not an elegant way.

```
project_ids = 
manager.serial_tasks.map{|st|
  st.tasks.map{|t|
    t.project.id
  }
}.flatten
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

```
has_many :tasks, through: :serial_tasks
```

to the Manager class. Querying than should be pretty straightforward.

If you really want to just get the IDs you could then do something like:

```
project_ids = manager.tasks.pluck(:id)
```